# DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, jpa, orm

For some reason I'm getting this exception for a couple of records in my DB (<10 when total > 30K).
I'm almost sure that this is not caused because of null values.
So my question is : "Is there any other reason to get this exception except null value"?

Here is my code:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "a")  
@SequenceGenerator(name = "a_sequence", sequenceName = "a_sequence", allocationSize = 1)  
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "a_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b")
    private B fieldB;
}

@Entity  
@Table(name = "b")  
@SequenceGenerator(name = "b_sequence", sequenceName = "b_sequence", allocationSize = 1)  
public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "b_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;
}
```

And here is my stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: ***.***.domain.A.fieldB
    at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
```

**Update:**
Code that causing an error

```
A a = getManager().find(A.class, id);  
dozerBeanMapper.map(anotherAobject, a);  
getManager().merge(a);
```

Most likely that at second line fieldB at object a becomes null, but according to my logs this is not true, because fieldB in object anotherAobject is not null. The problem is that I have no possibility to connect to my app in debug mode. I have added more logs so that may give some information. 
But if I'm right and after mapping from anotherAobject to a fieldB is not null, then what could cause this exception?

**Update:**

Issue was caused by a null value. Question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to involve a null value, but not necessarily in the DB itself. For example, it could happen if you try to create a new instance of `A` without calling `setFieldB()` on it, and then you try to persist that `A` entity.

Comment: This is pretty much obvious, and this is not my case.
Is there any other reasons to get this exception?

Comment: The same could happen if you somehow set `fieldB` to null for a managed entity, but I guess this is also obvious. Could you show the part of the code where the exception occurs? I may help to give some context.